# gcc options for a freescale iMX6q ARM processor

Tags: gcc, arm, toolchain

I am trying to figure out gcc options for a toolchain I am setting up, for development board:
Sabre-lite which is based around the Freescale's iMX6q quad processor.

Now I know that iMX6 is basically a cortex-a9 processor that has co-processors vfpv3 and neon, and also vector graphics, 2D and even 3D engines.

However, the release notes and use guide docs haven't been too clear on how to enable any options that can be enabled in gcc.

In fact the options that I can 'play' with are the following.

```
-march= armv7-a                - ok this one is pretty obvious.
-mfpu= vfpv3/neon              - i can use only the vfpv3 co-processor, or both (respectively, depends on option)
-mfloat-abi=softfp/soft/hard   - I guess I can choose hard here, as there is hardware for fp operations
-mcpu=cortex-a9                - is it option even necessary? it is not clear if it just an alias for -march or something else.
```

Are there other options I should enable?
Why does the toolchain have as default options to build the linux kernel/uboot/packages  the following:

```
-march= armv7-a -mfpu= vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=softfp
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your -mfloat-abi should match whichever ABI is used on your system. softfp also uses floating point hardware, but the calling convention differs. You can check with "readelf -A /bin/ls" (for example). "Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers" means hard.

Comment: (Of course, if you are compiling natively on your target system using the system's native gcc, whatever is the correct ABI will be the default in the compiler, and can be omitted.)

Comment: I found the follwing relevant entries (using readelf). I trust the scream "softfp"?   `Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3` and `Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP`

Comment: None of those scream softfp, but if there is no Tag_ABI_VFP_args: in there, then that absence in itself does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-mthumb -O3 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -mvectorize-with-neon-quad -mfloat-abi=softfp`. Note that by default the compiler will not vectorize floating-point operating using NEON because NEON does not support denormal numbers. If you are fine with some loss of precision you can make gcc use NEON for floating-point by adding `-ffast-math` switch.

Comment: hey there, please elaborate a bit more. Why should I use softfp and not hard? Also -O3, is too aggresive optimisation for the sake of linux kernel. no? I mean I risk having nightmares trying to compile u-boot , kernel and packages. no? thank you for the rest of the options

Comment: The difference between softfp and hard is the way how floating-point parameters are passed and it depends on the Linux distribution you use. Since the default in your compiler is softfp, it is likely that your Linux distribution passes floating-point parameters in integer registers (however, it still can use hardware FPU for FP operations). If you want to compile just Linux kernel or U-boot, don't change compiler defaults; the options above are for compiling userspace programs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer everything, but that '--softfp' means to use the FPU, but maintain compatibility with code that doesn't.

[Slightly outdated ARM FP document](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort#Background_information)