# g++ Compile from x86 for ARM Cortex

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, arm

i want to compile from my workstation for a ARM Cortex-9a.
I found this  [gcc options for a freescale iMX6q ARM processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962447/gcc-options-for-a-freescale-imx6q-arm-processor)

If I'm right, it's possible to do this ?
I've using

```
gcc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388]
```

and want to compile with the flags listed ([here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options))

```
g++ -O3 -mtune=cortex-a9 main.cc -o main.o -c
main.cc:1:0: error: bad value (cortex-a9) for -mtune= switch
 #include <stdio.h>
 ^
```

do i really need the toolchains ? I thought that they are only for "simpler" usage ?

**EDIT**
for me, using crosstools-ng is the best & easiest way

Comment: You need a cross-compiler.

Comment: @EOF, thanks i only found cross-armv7hl-gcc49 this package or cross-armv6hl-gcc49 but i use a cortex 9a :-/

Comment: ARM instruction-set version numbering is confusing. I *think* cortex9a is arm7, but don't quote me on that. edit: Wikipedia agrees, it's arm7a. (confused yet?)

Comment: @EOF, yes :D the package manager from opensuse really confuses me too :) i think i will try to build it from scratch :-/

Comment: Have a look at [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) for building a cross-compiler; it takes away some of the headache.

Comment: Most of the headache, actually :)

Comment: It's not the package-manager's fault. It's ARM's stupid nomenclature. The names for their micro-architectures are not properly name-spaced from the instruction-set version names.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use Freescale's free compiler? I'm sure there must be a way to use it as a command-line tool (I can understand why anyone would want to avoid Eclipse).

Comment: thanks for the many replays ! for learning ive tried it with this tutorial: http://www.lowlevel.eu/wiki/ARM_Cross-Compiler all went good. but now i tried to compile with arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ i get fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
some ideas ? :-/

Comment: Unless you specifically want to fiddle about building toolchains and libraries, I'd suggest using prebuilt binary distributions with all the libraries, search paths, etc. pre-configured - e.g. [the Linaro ones](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/)